# How can I use compile & use multiple similar c++ library together?

Tags: c++, rust, compilation

I want to use 5 complex c++ libraries in Rust written by other open-sources projects at once. Those libraries have a similar structure: utils, parser, ast, simple interface. Those interfaces can be altered easily, however, those utils, parsers and asts share the same function name but have different implementations.

e.g:

```
create_ast(){//src/a/utils.cpp
    extract_a_tree();
}

create_ast(){//src/b/utils.cpp
   init_graph();
   init_view();
}

#define //src/a/define.h, this one is written in c++11 standard
SQL_UPDATE 301
SQL_REPLACE 302

#define //src/b/define.h, this one is written in c++17 standard
SQL_INSERT 998
SQL_UPDATE 302

TypeA* generate_a(){//src/a/interface.h
  //do sth
}


TypeB* generate_b(){//src/b/interface.h
  //do sth B
}
```

I have tried to change those files by myself to make irrelevant symbols internal(anonymous namespace+static), yet complex macros & some auto-generated code(still, same function name, different implementation details) exist in those libraries make it hard to finish.

Can I compile those c++ libraries so that only functions in src/a/interface.h or src/b/inferface.h can be seen by rust or other program use those library?

Now I can compile a.a, b.a, c.a, d.a, e.a with default compiler flags but I can not use them together.

Comment: Not entirely sure what your question is here, but using [bindgen](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-bindgen/) you can generate Rust declarations from the C++ headers for only the functions/types/variables of interest?  Separately generating bindings for each origin library, each in its own namespace (crate or module), will avoid any issues with conflicting names (alternatively, you could register a callback that [renames items](https://docs.rs/bindgen/0.55.1/bindgen/callbacks/trait.ParseCallbacks.html#method.item_name)).

Comment: @eggyal The problem is that a.a use functions in b.a in a weird way... I can call a::func1(), a::func1() called a::func2() and then a::func2 called b::func3(). Finally I solved this problem by giving any functions/structs auto-generated a unique prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using the following procedure:

1. calm down and believe you are a robot.
2. give every .cpp & .h a unique namespace when it can be easily done. (e.g: namespace_a{})
3. For that hard-to-add-namespace source files, in this project,  they usually generated by flex + bison.
   use %option prefix="any_name_I_like" in flex
   use %define api.prefix {any_name_I_like} in bison.y

P.S:  using -wl, -BSymbolic can safely pass the compiling and linking process, however, It acts weird.

> generate_a called create_ast()(IN A)

> create_ast()(IN A) called parse()(IN A)

> parse()(IN A) called deep_create()(IN B)

Obviously, the symbol table mixed up together.